# xsl:value-of select="substring-before when there is an illegal xml character

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

I'm using an XSLT on another XML file to extract the number of feet in a measurement of film.
In the native XML, my measurement includes the foot symbol of the single straight quote: '
How can I use the substring function to get just the number without the '?
I'm trying to use this

```
<instantiationDimensions unitsOfMeasure="Feet">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(Original/ReelSize, ''')"/>
</instantiationDimensions>
```

but that isn't working. I have tried the same code escaping the character

```
 <instantiationDimensions unitsOfMeasure="Feet">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(Original/ReelSize, '&apos;')"/>
</instantiationDimensions>
```

But also no luck.

Comment: The search "escaping quotes in XPath" finds 170 almost identical questions, most of them with answers. Did you do any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select='substring-before(Original/ReelSize, "&apos;")'/>
```

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Introduction